# Amazon S3 Website & MySQL Backup

Tags: php, mysql, scripting, amazon-s3, backup

I have a website (a digital asset management system/gallery - http://www.resourcespace.org) that has a huge amount of images. The total size of the website, including the images is approximately 6gb.

The website is in PHP and uses a MySQL database.

What is the best way to automatically backup the website & MySQL database and push to Amazon S3 each night?

Are there any readily available scripts out there that can do this?

Comment: Just found this if anyone is interested... looks quite good & will investigate http://website2backup.com

Comment: I develop http://website2backup.com :) The problem is the 6gb it is huge, too big for PHP. As PHP cannot manipulate files of more than 2gb the archive cannot be completed. If you really want to use a PHP solution you must do several backups of your website. For example if your gallery is organized by months do a backup for each month. The incremental files backup functionality of W2B allow you to use less storage and resources, but a full backup is regularly needed. Adding files to archives can be resources consuming for your web hosting, smallest archives do faster backups.

Comment: @Axel - PHP on a 64bit system can handle files more than 2GB in size.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet dealt with size of data that you are referring to.  However, I did find this handy script and tweaked it to push my backup files to Amazon S3.

https://github.com/woxxy/MySQL-backup-to-Amazon-S3

If you have not already seen the recent announcement for Amazon Glacier, you should take a look.  It may be more along the lines of what you need for pure backups.

http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/